# If you get permanent shadow points without a Bout of Madness, do you still get a Degeneration?

Tags: the-one-ring

My question is about what happens when you get Permanent Shadow Points without a Bout of Madness.

In TOR you normally only get Permanent Shadow Points by becoming Miserable, rolling an Eye of Sauron, and thus suffering a Bout of Madness. This causes you to gain 1 Permanent Shadow Point and gain a Degeneration.

However, there are two other circumstances that I know of that can produce more Permanent Shadow Points:

- In the Rivendell supplement there is a Fellowship Phase Undertaking called "There and Back Again." This causes you to gain 1 Permanent Shadow Point, but in return you get some hope back.
- Characters who wish to gain the Shadow-Lore specialty from Saruman may study with him, but in return they gain 1 Permanent Shadow Point.

If you gain a Permanent Shadow Point in these circumstances, do you still gain a Degeneration? I can't find anything that firmly says if you do or do not.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

### Degeneration only occurs with a Bout of Madness

From The One Ring (core rulebook) p226:

> **Degeneration**
>
> In addition to ‘resetting’ his Shadow score, **every time a hero suffers a bout of madness** he develops a Flaw, a negative Distinctive Feature.

The above does **not** say that Degeneration occurs "every time a hero gains a permanent shadow point" - the only trigger for Degeneration is the Bout of Madness